# Dn denotes the squares of a 2-by-n board using plain dominos. Then we see D1 = 1, D2= 2, and D3 = 3. find more values of Dn and guess an expression.

Tags: induction

I understand this problem that this sequence is a Fibonacci sequence. Also, Fibonacci series is f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2). However, I am stuck on how to prove this using strong induction.

I am at this step: Dk+1 = Dk + Dk-1. I do not where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is unclear. ... what exactly is $D_n$?

Comment: I strongly suspect you are asking exactly [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080310/find-a-recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-ways-to-arrange-n-dominoes-to-fil) the number of ways to cover a $2 \times n$ board with dominoes but you have not made it clear at all.